# Travel from Venice, Italy to Cologne, Germany

Tags: germany, italy, ride-sharing

Unfortunately, I missed my Ryan air flight from Venice to Cologne (Köln). Now I am in trouble. What can be optimal way by bus or train? Or where can I get some rideshare facility?

Comment: [Check rome2rio for ideas](http://www.rome2rio.com/de/s/Venice/Cologne). There are many rather obvious solutions (rebook on Ryanair, Germanwings for about €100, indirect flights with Air Berlin, KLM or Austrian for €200-300, a flight from or to another airport, a night train with a connection in Munich for €230) but what are your requirements? Leave ASAP? Cheap above all else?

Comment: I am trying to buy some ticket from ltur. I tried to rebook, but they can not provide before friday.

Comment: I might be wrong but I was under the impression that they specialize in vacations/packages. If you just need a flight, you can use the many search engines/OTA or go directly to the website of the relevant airline. Have you tried that? Also, you still haven't answered my questions, if you want good advice, you need to add those details to your question.

Comment: Hi, actually, i need to be in köln by tomorrow evening and i tried some flight option. I can only take train , bus or rideshare.

Comment: Check www.blablacar.it to share a car.

Comment: So, somehow i solved the situation. I came to verona from venice( costs 8:60 euro), then i have taken train EC 188 which costs 76 euro and i will reach  München at 10:30 pm aproximately. I have already booked a ticket from München to Köln from LTUR which is prety cheap 25 euro. It will leave München at 12:01 am and will reach Köln at 7:30 am aprixametly. So my total expense is 110 euro and going to take 16 hour almost!! So, my suggestion is: never travel without a passport in Europe, even if you have residence permit.

Comment: Ryanair is far more strict about ID than is required by law. They're the only airline where you absolutely must have your passport for intra-Schengen flights...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How much money do you want to spend? There is a train connection overnight:

Venezia Santa Lucia Di, 10.03.15    dep 20:57       CNL40236    City Night Line
München Hbf Mi, 11.03.15    arr 06:10   11

transfer time 20 Min.

München Hbf Mi, 11.03.15    dep 06:30   14  ICE 692 Intercity-Express
Mannheim Hbf    Mi, 11.03.15    arr 09:29   2

transfer time 7 Min.

Mannheim Hbf    Mi, 11.03.15    dep 09:36   3   ICE 202 Intercity-Express
Köln Hbf    Mi, 11.03.15    arr 11:05   4

Costs about 230 Euro in a coach and starts at 245 Euro in a sleeper car.

You can see the timetable and book the journey on www.bahn.de (http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query.exe/en?S=Venezia+Santa+Lucia&Z=Koeln+Hbf&time=20:00&date=10.03.15&start=1&)

Comment: Can you post a link so that the OP can verify these (and possibly others) train schedules and fares?